# Отсутствуют пакеты в виртуальном окружении Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

при создании нового окружения или при повторном открытие проекта автоматически запускается виртуальное окружение без python и pip. То есть при обращение к python  я получаю
' "python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.' Даже при попытке выйти я получаю: ' "deactivate" не является внутренней или внешней '
Но при удалении виртуального окружения и создания нового через консоль, то с ним все нормально.

Answer (score 0):

> получаю ' "pytyon" не является внутренней или внешней командой,
> исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.'

Правильно получаете, потому что команда `python`, а не "`pytyon`"

Comment: Извините, это я ошибся в вопросе, с командой "python" такая же ернуда.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше окружение было создано как неперемещаемое и было перемещено. Т.Е. сменился путь расположения python.